# Bash comparing two different files with different fields

Tags: bash

I am not sure if this is possible to do but I want to compare two character values from two different files. If they match I want to print out the field value in slot 2 from one of the files. Here is an example

```
# File 1 
Date D
Tamb B

# File 2
F gge0001x gge0001y gge0001z
D 12-30-2006 12-30-2006 12-30-2006
T 14:15:20 14:15:55 14:16:27
B 15.8 16.1 15
```

Here is my thought behind the problem I want to do

```
if [ (field2) from (file1) == (field1) from (file2) ] ; do
    echo (field1 from file1) and also (field2 from file2) on the same line

which prints out "Date 12-30-2006" 
                 "Tamb 15.8"
                 " ... "
```

and continually run through every line from essentially file 1 printing out any matches that there are. I am assuming these will need to be some sort of array involved. Any thoughts on if this is the correct logic and if this is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reformats file2 based on the abbreviations found in file1:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next;} $1 in a {print a[$1],$2;}' file1 file2
Date 12-30-2006
Tamb 15.8
```

#### How it works

- `FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next;}`

  This reads each line of file1 and saves the information in array `a`.

  In more detail, `NR` is the number of lines that have been read in so far and `FNR` is the number of lines that have been read in so far from the current file. So, when `NR==FNR`, we know that awk is still processing the first file.  Thus, the array assignment, `a[$2]=$1` is only performed for the first file.  The statement `next` tells awk to skip the rest of the code and jump to the `next` line.
- `$1 in a {print a[$1],$2;}`

  Because of the `next` statement, above, we know that, if we get to this line, we are working on file2.

  If field 1 of file2 matches any a field 2 of file1, then print a reformatted version of the line.

Comment: This only does the first line `Date 12-30-2006` .. how can I get it to loop through the entire file?

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart When I run it (as shown above), it goes through all of file2 including the last line `B 15.8 16.1 15`.  Just to be clear, does it not do that for you?  Or, are you having problems with files that are different from the examples in the question?

Comment: Yeah It does... I am sorry I made some modifications to my file1 and thats why It was wrong. This works perfectly as intended. I am curious however what `FNR==NR` is or does exactly? I understand the rest of the code

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart Glad it is working.  `FNR==NR` is an awk idiom to tell if we are working on the first file listed on the command line or not.  I added an explanation for how it does that to the answer.